# How to fix pygame music playing multiple times?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game using pygame. It plays a "game over" music when the player dies but it plays it multiple times. I made the loops to 0 but it again plays it multiple times.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# creating our window
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("My First Game")

# creating our icon
game_icon = pygame.image.load('logo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(game_icon)

# player variables
player_x = 0
player_y = 240

# jumping variables
is_jump = False
jump_count = 10

# enemy variables
enemy_x = 100
enemy_y = 240
enemy_left = False
enemy_right = True

# dead variable
is_dead = False

# score and score timer variables
score = 0
score_timer = 0

# main loop
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    # checking if user pressed the exit button(he probly rage quit) then quiting our game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # controls
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # left control
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player_x != 0:
        player_x -= 5
    # right control
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player_x != 735:
        player_x += 5
    # jump control
    if not(is_jump) and not(is_dead):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            is_jump = True
            pygame.mixer.music.load("jump.wav")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    elif not(is_dead):
        if jump_count >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jump_count < 0:
                neg = -1
            player_y -= (jump_count ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jump_count -= 1
        else:
            is_jump = False
            jump_count = 10

    # drawing player and enemy
    if not(is_dead):
        player = pygame.draw.rect(
            win, (255, 0, 0), (player_x, player_y, 64, 64))
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (enemy_x, enemy_y, 64, 64))

    # enemy movement
    if enemy_right:
        enemy_x = enemy_x + 5
        if enemy_x == 735:
            enemy_right = False
            enemy_left = True
    if enemy_left:
        enemy_x = enemy_x - 5
        if enemy_x == 0:
            enemy_left = False
            enemy_right = True

    # checking collision between enemy and player
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        is_dead = True

    # checking if collision has happend and player died
    if is_dead:
        # displaying game over if player is dead
        font_over = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 64)
        game_over = font_over.render("Game Over", True, (255, 255, 255))
        win.blit(game_over, (230, 200))
        # dead sound
        pygame.mixer.music.load("over.wav")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

    # displaying score
    font_score = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
    score_text = font_score.render(
        "Score: " + str(score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    win.blit(score_text, (0, 0))

    # score and score timer
    if not(is_dead):
        score_timer += 1
        if score_timer == 60:
            score += 1
            score_timer = 0

    # updating our window and filling it black
    pygame.display.update()
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

# quiting the game if user no longer whants to play
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only exiting the main game loop (while run) if the player exits.
And you are running the code to play the game over music in every iteration of the loop, so once the is_dead variable is set to true the game over music code will repeat every time the main loop is run (so until the user quits the application).

To fix this you could declare a variable `hasPlayedGameOverSound = False`. Probably right after you declare the is_dead variable would be best.
Then change the two lines after the # dead sound comment to

```
if not hasPlayedGameOverSound:
    pygame.mixer.music.load("over.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    hasPlayedGameOverSound = True
```

This should ensure that the game over sound only plays once

Comment: This answer would be better if it also explained how to fix the problem.